# MIPS assembly: instruction "beq" and the 'and' operator

Tags: assembly, mips

Can I use the 'and' operator with 'beq' in MIPS conditional statements?

For example, in C, I can write `if(arr[0]=='a' && arr[1]=='b' && arr[2]=='c')`, but how can I write like this code in MIPS assembly?

Comment: Rewrite with single condition `if` and `goto` in C. If you can do that, you can follow the same logic in assembly. Alternatively, draw a flowchart (single conditions here as well). Hint: try to negate the condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, we combine flow of control with logic of the conditions we're testing.  As [Jester is telling you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598653/mips-assembly-beq-and#comment103509880_58598653), we can do/observe this in C, which is often friendlier for these transformations than assembly.

You can see that:

```c
if(arr[0]=='a' && arr[1]=='b' && arr[2]=='c') { ... }
```

is equivalent to:

```c
if (arr[0]=='a') {
    if (arr[1] == 'b') {
        if (arr[2] == 'c') {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

So, if you know how to do `if (x == y) { ... }` then just apply that three times.

---

In assembly language our only decision control flow construct is "if-goto", and of course  only simple conditions can be tested.

So, to do `if (x==y) { then-part } else { else-part }`, using an "if-goto" style, we test `x==y` and upon that condition being *false* we branch around the `then-part` and to the `else-part`.  Since we are branching on condition false, then when the condition is true, we fail to branch and run the `then-part` that we program immediately following the condition test.

Since we're branching on condition false, then for all practical purposes, we write, in "if-goto" style in C: `if (x!=y) goto ElseLabel;` followed by the then the `then-part` translation...

---

For reference, see the following posts:

- [An example of Assembly Language Flow Control](https://www.codementor.io/erikeidt/an-example-in-assembly-language-control-flow-zrm98znvo)
- [Transforming Structured Statements into Assembly Language](https://www.codementor.io/erikeidt/conditional-logic-in-assembly-language-majw7ofjh)
- [Conditional Branching in various Instruction Sets](https://www.codementor.io/erikeidt/conditional-branching-in-instruction-set-architecture-zw58jo30j)
- [Short Circuit Expressions](https://www.codementor.io/erikeidt/conditional-logic-in-assembly-language-majw7ofjh#short-circuit-expression-transformation)

Answer (score 0):

No, `beq` takes 2 registers and compares them, that is all.  Remember, assembly language reflects what machine code can do in one instruction.  Doing something more complicated often requires more instructions.

To `&&` multiple conditions together, you need either

- multiple `beq` and/or `bne` instructions; a chain of branches
- or create a value in one register that represents the logical and of multiple conditions before branching.  For example, load all 3 bytes and `xori` them with `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` respectively.  (Producing `0` for a match).   Then `or` those results together and see if the final result is `0` (with a `bne` or `beq` against `$zero`)  If so, there were no mismatching bits in any of the 3 bytes so the condition is true.

The 2nd way optimizes away the short-circuit eval that the C logic has.  Note that in the C expression, `a[1]` isn't even accessed if `a[0] != 'a'`, so it wouldn't fault even if `a` was a pointer to the last byte of a page, and the next page was unmapped.  (Assuming `a[0] == 0` or something, an empty 0-terminated string).

But if you *do* know you can safely access all 3 bytes of the string/array, this is an option.

It's easier / more effective as an optimization when the condition is something like `if (x < 5 && y < 10)` which you can implement with 2x `slti` instructions to compare into registers, AND those regs together, then `beq $t0, $zero, skip_if_body`

---

**In this special case where you're checking 3 contiguous bytes, it's basically `memcmp(a, "abc", 3)`**.

If you know that `a` is word-aligned, you can do a word load to get the 3 bytes you want, plus one byte of garbage we need to ignore.

MARS simulates a little-endian MIPS system, so the 3 bytes we want are the 3 least-significant bytes in the word.  (In general MIPS can run as big or little-endian.)

```
# assuming a[] is a word-aligned static array
# and little-endian MIPS

    lw   $t0,  a             # pseudo-instruction for lui / lw to construct the full address
    li   $t1,  'abc' << 8    # 0x63626100  if your assemble doesn't like multi-char literals

    sll  $t0, $t0, 8         # shift out the 4th byte which we need to ignore
    bne  $t0, $t1, skip_if_body
         # if body: a[0] == 'a' && a[1] == 'b' && a[2] == 'c'
         ...
skip_if_body:
    ...
    jr $ra
```

You can of course also use this if `a` is actually a pointer in a register which is known to be word-aligned.  `lw  $t0, ($a0)`.

I shifted the unwanted byte out of the load instead of masking it with AND because `andi` can't encode `0x00FFFFFF`.

If `a` wasn't known to be aligned, possibly `lwl`/`lwr` for an unaligned load would have been worth using.

Or `lhu` + `lbu` to load 16 bits and 8 bits separately if we have 2-byte alignment; we can check 16 bits at once with `xori` making use of the full width of the immediate, if we still want to combine for one branch.  Or just with `li`/`beq`.

Constructing `'abc' << 8` in a register takes 2 instructions (`lui + addiu` or `ori`)

Answer (score 0):

No, you would instead just do two `beq` instructions to account for both conditions.